# Dataflow not showing output collection count for streaming pipeline?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a streaming pipeline which reads from Pubsub. I am using apache beam python sdk 2.10.

My pipeline contains different stages.
I am able to see input and output collection counts in First stage while we are reading from pubsub using ReadFromPubsub. However in 2nd stage only input collection count is showing, output collection count is blank.

In my final stage I am writing to BigQuery.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Support for streaming pipelines with Apache Beam Python SDK on Google Cloud Dataflow is in Beta](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/dataflow-stream-processing-now-supports-python).

Some features are not fully supported, and that's the case for some monitoring metrics. These will gradually be added as support is improved.

The counters are not available, but you can add your own using a metrics counter, like so:

```
from apache_beam.metrics import Metrics

def debug(msg):
  Metrics.counter('elementCounts', 'filePaths').inc()
  # The rest of your code....
```

Does that help?

Comment: I tried this solution but does not seems to help. The counts are still not showing at that step output collection. I am expecting the counts to show in dataflow dashboard. Does this solution will show the count at dataflow dashboard UI?